# How to add UISLIDER in Android cocos2d

Tags: android, android-emulator, cocos2d-android

Hi,

I am doing one app here I am doing small game using cocos2d in Android. I need to display uislide but I don't know how to display. I tried but I don't have any idea and I am doing app below code like I taken surfaceview dynamically please any one suggest me how to display slider and how to get imageviews, textviews into xml files.

HelloWorldLayer:

```
public class HelloWorldLayer extends CCColorLayer {
    static HelloWorldLayer layer;
    CGSize winSize;
    CCSprite home,target;
    protected HelloWorldLayer(ccColor4B color) {
        super(color);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        winSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().displaySize();
        this.setIsTouchEnabled(true);
        home= CCSprite.sprite("banana.png");
        home.setPosition(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
        this.addChild(home);
    }

    public static CCScene scene() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Creates scene  
        CCScene scene = CCScene.node();

        layer = new HelloWorldLayer(ccColor4B.ccc4(225, 225,225, 225));

        //adds layer to scene
        scene.addChild(layer);

        return scene;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean ccTouchesEnded(MotionEvent event) {
        CGPoint location = CCDirector.sharedDirector().convertToGL(CGPoint.ccp(event.getX(), event.getY()));

        if (CGRect.containsPoint(home.getBoundingBox(), location)) { 

            CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(CCFadeTransition.transition(0.5f,GamestartLayer.scene()));
            removeAllChildren(true);  
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add UI view in cocos2d game activity dynamically as

```
EditText txv=new EditText(context);
txv.setText("ABC");
CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity().addContentView(txv,layoutParams);
```

You can use same to use other UIview of android.

Comment: can we use the EditText in the GameLayer class??